# How to make bootable flash device using Linux to install win10

Tags: linux, bootable

I have a problem making bootable flash drive containing Windows 10.

I have tried 3 suggested solutions:

1. using `woeusb --tgt-fs NTFS -d win10.iso /dev/sdd` got error:

   ```
   dd: writing to '/dev/sdd2': No space left on device
   513+0 records in
   512+0 records out
   262144 bytes (262 kB, 256 KiB) copied, 0.595813 s, 440 kB/s
   The command "dd if="${download_directory}/uefi-ntfs.img" of="${uefi_ntfs_partition}"" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted

   lsblk
   sdd                 8:48   1  14.9G  0 disk  
   ├─sdd1              8:49   1  14.9G  0 part  
   └─sdd2              8:50   1   256K  0 part
   ```
2. using `dd if=win10.iso of /dev/sdd` simply does not recognized by bios;
3. using `syslinux` but have problem with filesystems, some files are bigger than 4GB, and it make it impossible to write to vfat. And I don't yet know how make syslinux to use ntfs.

I need to configure syslinux properly to boot .iso or unpacked one.

Comment: 1. How big is your flash device? 2. Which version of `woeusb` are you using? If possible, please try to follow *exactly* the tips of [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185). 3. If still problems, please try 'manually' according to the following link, [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy/windows-installer-for-big-files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy/windows-installer-for-big-files)